# vb.net copying file to another directory

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I want to copying file from selected directory path to another directory with same filename. i try this code,

```
Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click

    Try
        Dim openfile As New OpenFileDialog
        openfile.Filter = "JPG|*.jpeg;*.jpg|PNG|*.png"
        If (openfile.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
            TextBox3.Text = openfile.FileName
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

And then,

```
Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click

    Try
        Dim source As String = TextBox3.Text
        FileCopy(dest, source)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

error msg :

> "System.UnauthorizedAccessException : Acces to D:\resource is denied"

Comment: Make sure you have Write Access to the destination folder.

Comment: try other location rather D:\resource , change D drive to some other drive or give write access for the user to perform operation, rightly said by @Dr.Stitch..

Comment: File copy commands (post CP/M) usually go *source*, *destination*, IME. I guess you have code that uses the non-conventional way round.

Comment: What are the values of `dest` and `source`?

Comment: thanks for help, 
but i recognize that the mistake is the desDir is
"D:\resource" not "D:\resource\"

Answer (score 1):

An `UnauthorizedAccessException` occurs in below situation:

- User does not have the required permission.
- The file is in use.
- File Path is a directory.
- Path specified a read-only file.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that your variable `dest` refers to the destination directory. You need to combine it with the filename for the destination *filename*, not directory. Something like this...

```
Imports System.IO
'......
Dim destDir As String = "D:\resource"
Dim source As String = TextBox3.Text
Dim destFile As String = Path.Combine(destDir, Path.GetFileName(source))
FileCopy(source, destFile)
```

It would be better to use a variable to store the filename of the source rather than a control - if the TextBox is not set to be read-only then the user could accidentally change it.